# Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS - /boot is using 98.4% of 193MB

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I have a problem. I have noticed that my VPS is saying :

> => /boot is using 98.4% of 193MB

Looks like something went wrong, doesn't it?

I have tried to run `dpkg -l | grep linux` to check what's there.

Here is the output:

```
ii  libselinux1                        2.1.0-4.1ubuntu1             SELinux runt                                                                                                                                                             ime shared libraries
ii  linux-firmware                     1.79.7                       Firmware for                                                                                                                                                              Linux kernel drivers
iU  linux-generic-pae                  3.2.0.56.66                  Complete Gen                                                                                                                                                             eric Linux kernel
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-45             3.2.0-45.70                  Header files                                                                                                                                                              related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-45-generic-pae 3.2.0-45.70                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-48             3.2.0-48.74                  Header files                                                                                                                                                              related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-48-generic-pae 3.2.0-48.74                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-51             3.2.0-51.77                  Header files                                                                                                                                                              related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-51-generic-pae 3.2.0-51.77                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-52             3.2.0-52.78                  Header files                                                                                                                                                              related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-52-generic-pae 3.2.0-52.78                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-53             3.2.0-53.81                  Header files                                                                                                                                                              related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-53-generic-pae 3.2.0-53.81                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-54             3.2.0-54.82                  Header files                                                                                                                                                              related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-54-generic-pae 3.2.0-54.82                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-55             3.2.0-55.85                  Header files                                                                                                                                                              related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-55-generic-pae 3.2.0-55.85                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-56             3.2.0-56.86                  Header files                                                                                                                                                              related to Linux kernel version 3.2.0
ii  linux-headers-3.2.0-56-generic-pae 3.2.0-56.86                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              headers for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic-pae          3.2.0.56.66                  Generic Linu                                                                                                                                                             x kernel headers
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-29-generic-pae   3.2.0-29.46                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-45-generic-pae   3.2.0-45.70                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-48-generic-pae   3.2.0-48.74                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-51-generic-pae   3.2.0-51.77                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic-pae   3.2.0-52.78                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic-pae   3.2.0-53.81                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic-pae   3.2.0-54.82                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-55-generic-pae   3.2.0-55.85                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-3.2.0-56-generic-pae   3.2.0-56.86                  Linux kernel                                                                                                                                                              image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic-pae            3.2.0.56.66                  Generic Linu                                                                                                                                                             x kernel image
ii  util-linux                         2.20.1-1ubuntu3              Miscellaneou
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

What may I safely remove?

Answer (score 2):

You should just deinstall older versions. Normally there is no need to keep more than one (working version) beyond what you are running now.

Make sure you check first (with `uname`) if you actually rebooted after the last update (for the last version, 3.2.0-56, that would be today) and are running the latest version. And if you do remove all up but not including 3.2.0.55.

If you are running an older version, you should be able to delete all versions except for the one that is running and the last one (3.2.0.56), the others will never be started on a reboot, unless you would do so by hand. And for backup you keep your current, working, kernel.